# Getting Width and Height of an Inputted Picture in Python

Tags: python, file-io, pygame

Our assignment was to input a picture and create a program that writes a program that will draw that picture in python 2.7.5.  Here is my code:

```
from pygame import *

inFile = open("picture.jpg")
out = open('fa3.py','w')


width = inFile.get_width()
height = inFile.get_height()

out.write('''
from pygame import *
screen=display.set_mode((800,600))
running=True

while running:
    for evt in event.get():
        if evt.type == QUIT:
            running = False
            ''')


for i in range(width,height):
    c = inFile.get_at()
    out.write('''draw.cricle(screen,(c),x,y,2)''')
```

I am having trouble with getting the height and width of the file and also finding each individual pixel location in the image.  My teacher told me to use ".get_width and height" but it does not seem to work.  I know my x,y is not defined but that would be where each pixel location is inserted.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: I would not use pygame for this, you can use Image or PIL and it will be much more effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PIL Image module will be able to do what you want.

http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm

**Example to show an image**

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
im.show()
```

**The following additional code will let you manipulate the pixels (as long as you save it after)**

```
pixels = im.load()
print pixels[x, y]
pixels[x, y] = value    #value is a tuple in this format (normally) (235,154,124) or (Red,Green,Blue)
```

**To get the image size**

```
im.size()    #width and height, (400,600)
im.size[0]   #width, 400
im.size[1]   #height, 600
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PIL (Python Imaging Library) to do:

from PIL import image

im=Image.image("image.png")

pring im.size

width, height = im.size

If thats any help